# Find common values within groupby in pandas Dataframe based on two columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have following dataframe:

```
period    symptoms   recovery
1         4          2
1         5          2
1         6          2
2         3          1
2         5          2
2         8          4
2         12         6
3         4          2
3         5          2
3         6          3
3         8          5
4         5          2
4         8          4
4         12         6
```

I'm trying to find the common values of df['period'] groups (1, 2, 3, 4) based on value
of two columns 'symptoms' and 'recovery'

Result should be :

```
     symptoms   recovery   period
     5          2          [1, 2, 3, 4]
     8          4          [2, 4]
```

where each same two columns values has the periods occurrence in a list or column.

I'm I approaching the problem in the wrong way ? Appreciate your help.

I tried to turn each period into dict and loop through to find values but didn't work for me. Also tried to use grouby().apply() but I'm not getting a meaningful data frame.
Tried sorting values based on 3 columns but couldn't get the common ones between each period section.
Last attempt :

```
df2 = df[['period', 'how_long', 'days_to_ex']].copy()
#s = df.groupby(["period", "symptoms", "recovery"]).size()
 s = df.groupby(["symptoms", "recovery"]).size()
```

Comment: Maybe `.agg(list)` on the groupby? What happens to the other symptoms/recovery groups?

Comment: why the rest of `"symptoms", "recovery"` groups were ignored?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I tried .agg(list) and it worked well ! Thanks. I'm getting lists will all different occurrence, so I'm gonna filter out where list == len(periods) #4 . Is it a good approach ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm trying to find a sort of a pattern between all periods

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs: ah, you beat me to it...

Comment: @harryhaller, that's no problem, great answer :). Also have a look at pd.read_clipboard for reading the df ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# setup sample data
data = StringIO("""
period;symptoms;recovery
1;4;2
1;5;2
1;6;2
2;3;1
2;5;2
2;8;4
2;12;6
3;4;2
3;5;2
3;6;3
3;8;5
4;5;2
4;8;4
4;12;6
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")

# collect unique periods
df.groupby(['symptoms','recovery'])[['period']].agg(list).reset_index()
```

This gives

```
   symptoms  recovery        period
0         3         1           [2]
1         4         2        [1, 3]
2         5         2  [1, 2, 3, 4]
3         6         2           [1]
4         6         3           [3]
5         8         4        [2, 4]
6         8         5           [3]
7        12         6        [2, 4]
```

Comment: This is a solution and it worked well ! much appreciate it @harryhaller